# How to share local files from a .NET MVC project with another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution with two projects (virtually, two different websites) in .NET MVC. In one of them I have a form with some uploaded images, that are saved locally in a folder within the project folder. In the other project, I need to display the form data, including the uploaded images that are stored in the other project folder.

The way I went with for the moment was to just use the url of the files. But I think this isn't particularly refined... Is there a safer, more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You should store the files in some common place which is accessible to both the places.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, I assume so... But I don't know where. Since they can only access their own folders.